# find / remove duplicate records that don't have relation to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a Customers table with a columns called CustomerID, CustomerNumber.  I have an Orders table that references the CustomerID table in Customers.

I need to find and remove all duplicate records for CustomerNumber that DO NOT have orders in the Orders table.

This is how I am finding my duplicates in the Customers but I do not know how to filter out by the orders table then remove the extra records:

```
SELECT Name, CustomerNumber, COUNT(*) As DupeCount
FROM StagingCustomers 
WHERE ManufacturerID=15
GROUP BY Name, CustomerNumber
HAVING COUNT(CustomerNumber) > 1
ORDER BY CustomerNumber
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an `EXISTS` clause to check for any records without a relation:

```
SELECT Name, CustomerNumber, COUNT(*) As DupeCount
FROM StagingCustomers S
WHERE ManufacturerID=15
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from Orders WHERE CustomerID = S.CustomerID)
GROUP BY Name, CustomerNumber
HAVING COUNT(CustomerNumber) > 1
ORDER BY CustomerNumber
```

**EDIT:**

Example of how to delete records below.  This will set `IsDeleted` to 1 for every record that meets the above criteria, AND is not the lowest `customerid` per `CustomerNumber`.  For a clearer answer you need to give your table layout and relations.

```
UPDATE  S
SET IsDeleted = 1
FROM StagingCustomers S
WHERE ManufacturerID=15
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from Orders WHERE CustomerID = S.CustomerID)
AND CustomerID NOT IN (SELECT CustomerNumber, MIN(CustomerID)
                       FROM StagingCustomers
                       GROUP BY CustomerNumber)
GROUP BY Name, CustomerNumber
HAVING COUNT(CustomerNumber) > 1
ORDER BY CustomerNumber
```

Comment: nice, so then how do I get rid of these duplicates?

Comment: Change the `SELECT` to a `DELETE` and they are gone!

Comment: will they all be gone or just the dupes?  I need to leave 1 copy of each.  And actually I need to do a soft deleted where I set IsDeleted =1

Comment: Which ones do you want to delete?  How do you decide which of the duplicates is "good"?

Comment: I just need 1 left of each, so if there were 2 leave 1 not marked as IsDeleted, if there are 4 dupes still leave just 1 not marked as IsDeleted

Comment: @Slee - but how do you tell them apart?  Do you have an ID field, or a date, or something else?

Comment: So you need to decide which one you want to keep (highest or lowest ID), and then you can use a `NOT IN` subquery for the records you want to keep

Comment: do you have an example?  I am stumped

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work too:

```
SELECT Name, CustomerNumber, COUNT(*) As DupeCount
FROM StagingCustomers AS SC
LEFT JOIN ORDERS AS OD ON SC.CustomerID = OD.CustomerID
WHERE OD.CustomerID IS NULL AND ManufacturerID = 15
GROUP BY Name, CustomerNumber
HAVING COUNT(CustomerNumber) > 1
ORDER BY CustomerNumber
```

NOTE: Did not test the code, might need to tweak.